# How to customise DefaultScheduleEvent and create our own event in PrimeFaces schedule

Tags: primefaces

By default PrimeFaces DefaultScheduleEvent have the following attributes
Title, Description, start date, end date etc.
My question is how to include one or more custom attribute in schedule event.

Comment: By extending like you do in normal java

Comment: Ok i'll try your suggetsion

Comment: I extended that java class and it's working fine but now how can i refer that attribute in jsf page like ManagedBean.event.title

Comment: Uhhmm... like you'd refer to any other property in any other bean `#{event.customField}`. I assume you tried this.

Comment: I'm using my own ScheduleRenderer and in my managed bean how can i initialize customized scheduleevent interface. ex: private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

Comment: Uhhhh.... `new MyOwnScheduleEvent()` ? What is your basic java knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

A not so technical workaround that I used to generate a customized detail dialog is to determine the object type through styleClasses, for example:

```
    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
    if (eventModel == null) {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        /* 
        *  Just fill your model with a couple things, setting a  specific styleClass
        *  for each type. Btw, you can also use this to give a specific appearance
        *  to each data type
        */

        for(Activity act: myActivities){
            event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(act.getActName(), act.getStartDate(), act.getEndDate(),"activity");
            eventModel.addEvent(event);
        }

        for(Meeting meet : myMeetings){
            event = new DefaultScheduleEvent(meet.getMeetPurpose(), meet.getStartDate(), meet.getEndDate(),"meeting");
            eventModel.addEvent(event);
        }
    }
    return eventModel
}

public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    if(selectEvent.getStyleClass().contains("activity")){
        /*
        *   Search for object on DB and do stuff.
        */
    }
}
```

In my `onEventSelect` you can use a `searchForActivity(event.getTitle(), event.getStartDate(), event.getEndDate())` on your Session Bean to get all the info related to this specific object. Then you can build a regular view with the retrieved object.

I know this might not be the **best** way to achieve a "*custom event*", but will allow you to create whatever class you need and build views based on what you want to show to the user.

Hope it helps, kind regards :)

Comment: And why did a simple overriding of the Java DefaultScheduleEvent class not work?